# Swift Programming: getter/setter in stored property

Tags: ios, swift

How do I overwrite the setter of stored property in Swift?

In Obj-C, I can overwrite its setter, but Swift doesn't seem to be happy about getter/setters being used for stored property.

Say I have a `Card` class with a property called `rank`. I don't want the client to give it any invalid value, therefore, in objective-C, I can overwrite `setRank` so that it performs additional check. But `willSet` in Swift doesn't seem to help because `newValue` is constant and it makes no sense to assign `rank` because setter will be called in a loop.

Comment: Have you found a way of doing this? I need this kind of functionality myself...

Comment: I found it. Check out my answer...

Comment: What about didGet or analog?

Answer (score 109, accepted):

Ok. Reading through Apples documentation on Swift I found [this](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/swift/conceptual/swift_programming_language/Properties.html):

> If you assign a value to a property within its own didSet observer,
>   the new value that you assign will replace the one that was just set.

So all you have to do is this:

```
var rank: Int = 0 {
    didSet {
        // Say 1000 is not good for you and 999 is the maximum you want to be stored there
        if rank >= 1000  {
            rank = 999
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What about didGet or analog?

Comment: Not sure I understand your question. Can you be more specific, please?

Comment: I need to invoke some code before getting. I was able to perform this in obj-c but I cannot see how to perform this in Swift. The only thing I see is to use two properties: one is public and one is private, public invokes my code and return private property's value. That is why I asked about didGet

Comment: You can only have a getter for a computed property. For example `var rankTimesTwo: Int { get { return rank * 2 } }`

Comment: Works like a charm! Beware it won't be called when setting the property in init()

Answer (score 36):

You can't override `get`/`set` for a stored property but you can use property observers `willSet`/`didSet`:

```
var totalSteps: Int = 0 {
    willSet(newTotalSteps) {
        println("About to set totalSteps to \(newTotalSteps)")
    }
    didSet {
        if totalSteps > oldValue  {
            println("Added \(totalSteps - oldValue) steps")
        }
    }
}
```

The default parameter names are `newValue` for `willSet` and `oldValue` for `didSet`, or you can name them yourself as in `willSet(newTotalSteps)`.

Comment: This works. But doesn't solve my problem, maybe I wasn't clear enough in my original question.

Comment: Say I have a `Card` class with a property called `rank`. I don't want the client to give it any value, therefore, in objective-C, I can overwrite `setRank` so it performs additional check. But `willSet` in Swift doesn't seem to help because `newValue` is constant and it makes no sense to assign `rank` because setter will be called in a loop.

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what you mean but couldn't you use `didSet` to check `rank` after it gets set and if it fails validation, reset it to something else e.g. `oldValue`?

Answer (score 9):

get and set are for computed properties (they don't have any backing store). 
(In my opinion, the keyword 'var' is confusing here)

- willSet and didSet are called for an instance variable (Use didSet to override any changes)
- set and get are purely for computed properties

Answer (score 9):

If you don't want to use didSet, which has the problem that the property's value is temporarily wrong, you should wrap a computed property around it.

```
private var _foo:Int = 0
var foo:Int {
    get {
        return _foo
    }
    set {
        if(newValue > 999) {
            _foo = 999
        } else {
            _foo = newValue
        }
    }
}
```

Or:

```
private var _foo:Int = 0
var foo:Int {
    get {
        return _foo
    }
    set {
        guard newValue <= 999 else {
            _foo = 999
            return
        }
        _foo = newValue
    }
}
```

Comment: Its not make sense to use two variables.

Comment: This is only using one property (variable): `foo` is just a computed expression of `_foo`, don't let the "var" keyword fool you! It does mean that there are two entries accessible from the private namespace, but that has no bearing on protected/public and keeps the value of `foo` valid at all times. This is essentially the "view" pattern. The problem you get with *rewriting* via `didSet`, in addition to it having a period of being invalid, is that there's significant potential for an infinite loop since you're reentering the `didSet` handler from within `didSet`.

Answer (score -8):

### Simplified Example:

```
class Shape {
    var sideLength: Double {
    get {
        return self.sideLength
    }
    set {
        // Implement the setter here.
        self.sideLength = newValue
    }
    }
}
```

### Full example

Check out `perimeter` in this example.

Excerpt From: Apple Inc. “The Swift Programming Language.” iBooks. https://itun.es/us/jEUH0.l

```
class EquilateralTriangle: NamedShape {
    var sideLength: Double = 0.0

    init(sideLength: Double, name: String) {
        self.sideLength = sideLength
        super.init(name: name)
        numberOfSides = 3
    }

    var perimeter: Double {
    get {
        return 3.0 * sideLength
    }
    set {
        sideLength = newValue / 3.0
    }
    }

    override func simpleDescription() -> String {
        return "An equilateral triagle with sides of length \(sideLength)."
    }
}
var triangle = EquilateralTriangle(sideLength: 3.1, name: "a triangle")
triangle.perimeter
triangle.perimeter = 9.9
triangle.sideLength”
```

Comment: in this case, `perimeter` is still a computed property. How do I overwrite sideLength without introducing a computed property?

Comment: @bohanl I've added a simplified example using `get` and `set`

Comment: Your "full example" shows a computed property, not a stored property, and your "simplified example" doesn't work.

Comment: I stand corrected.  It's as if the abstraction of @property(auto-synthesized getters+setters) in Objective-C has been unabstracted in Swift. The irony...

Comment: You're "simplified example" is calling a getter within a getter of itself. Inf loop... crash.