# Overriding properties in swift

Tags: ios, swift, properties

For example a have a first class

```
public class MyBaseButton: UIButton {

    public var weight: Double = 1.0

    public var text: String? {
        get {
            return self.titleForState(.Normal)
        }
        set {
            return self.setTitle(newValue, forState: .Normal)
        }
    }
}
```

And inherited class:

```
public class SomeButton: SomeBaseButton {

    override public var text: String? = "text"
    override public var weight: Double = 2.0
}
```

So, the logic is that `SomeClass` define own text and weight.
But I'm getting an errors:

**For text**: "*Cannot override with a stored property 'text'*"

**For weight**: "*Cannot override with a stored property 'weight'*"

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Swift Programming: getter/setter in stored property](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24114732/swift-programming-getter-setter-in-stored-property)

Answer (score 58, accepted):

Interestingly this works just fine in pure Swift classes. For example, this works as expected:

```
public class FooButton {
    public var weight: Double = 1.0
}

public class BarButton: FooButton {
    override public var weight: Double = 2.0
}
```

The reason it does not work for you is because you are working with Objective-C classes: since `UIButton` is an Objective-C class, all its subclasses will be too. Because of that, the rules seem to be a bit different.

Xcode 6.3 is actually a bit more informative. It shows the following two errors:

> Getter for "weight" overrides Objective-C method "weight" from superclass "FooButton"
>   Setter for "weight" overrides Objective-C method "setWeight:" from superclass "Foobutton"

Since the following does work ...

```
public class BarButton: FooButton {
    override public var weight: Double {
        get {
            return 2.0
        }
        set {
            // Do Nothing
        }
    }
}
```

... my guess is that these methods are simply not synthesized correctly.

I wonder if this is a compiler bug. Or a shortcoming. Because I think it *could* handle the case.

Maybe the Swift designers thought that in case of overriding `weight` you could also simply set it to a different value in your initializer. Hm.

Comment: For me the first example of you doesn't compile. Not with Xcode 6.3.2 (Swift 1.2) nor with Xcode 7.0 beta (Swift 2.0). Just throws the compiler error: "Cannot override with a stored property weight"

Comment: Even easier: `override public var weight: Double { return 2.0 }`

Comment: @ixany definitely worked for me in Swift 4 for the CUSTOM property i was adding to a base view controller.

Answer (score 13):

In addition, if someone wants to override property to have `dynamic` effect, see [KVO](http://en.swifter.tips/kvo/)

```
class MyClass: NSObject {
    var date = NSDate()
}

class MyChildClass: MyClass {
    dynamic override var date: NSDate {
        get { return super.date }
        set { super.date = newValue }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

In the above you have a getter and a setter.

When you override it, you are just assigning it a value.

Instead set up the setter and getter as you have above.

```
var _text:Text

   override public var text: String? {
            get {
                return _text
            }
            set {
                _text = newValue
            }
        }
```

Comment: But I need "text" only as a default value. In your example it is not possible to change text property

Comment: Ok well then you just assign newValue to it

Comment: Add a private member variable and use that to store the data. You will need to put it in the super.

Comment: Aren't you missing the `override` keyword?

Answer (score 1):

I ran into this issue when trying to override the NSPredicateRowEditor `templateViews` property in Swift 3.

Superclass property to override:

```
open var templateViews: [NSView] { get }
```

Override like so:

```
class CustomRowTemplate: NSPredicateEditorRowTemplate {

    override var templateViews: [NSView] {
        get {
            let templateViews = super.templateViews

            // custom subclass work goes here

            return templateViews
        }
        //set {

        // Superclass property is `get` only, other properties might need a setter

        //}
    }

}
```