# How to override array var in child class?

Tags: swift, class, swift3, overriding

I have class Slider. Which slides array of advertisements [Advertisement]. Now I created sliderForFood which must slide foods array [Food]. How can I override my advertisement [Advertisement] var with foods[FOOD] var.

```
class SliderADV {
    var arrayAdvertisements: [Advertisement] = [Advertisement]()
}

class SliderForFood: SliderADV {
    var arrayFood:[Food] = [Food]()

     override var arrayAdvertisements: [Advertisement]{
        get {
           return arrayFood
           }
       set{
           if newValue is [ArrayFood]{
               self.arrayAdvertisement = newValue
          }
     }
}
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Overriding properties in swift](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28786597/overriding-properties-in-swift). Beside this, if `Food` _is a_ `Advertisement`, maybe it could also inherit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inheritance basically means "is a kind of". You're saying that "Slider for food *is a kind of* slider for ads" which does not make sense to me.

IMO, you should create a protocol like this:

```
protocol Slider {
    associatedtype ThingToSlide
    var things: [ThingToSlide] { get set }
}
```

Then you have your two slider classes conform to it:

```
class SliderForAds : Slider {
    typealias ThingToSlide = Advertisment
    var things: [Advertisment] = [Advertisment]()
}

class SliderForFood : Slider {
    typealias ThingToSlide = Food
    var things: [Food] = [Food]()
}
```

Comment: They are the same except array type ! That is why I decided to create child!

Comment: @YestayMuratov Even if they are exactly the same except the array's type, `SliderForFood` should not inherit from `SlideADV`.

Answer (score 1):

You should better do it following way - create an Item protocol and create two implementations of this i.e Advertisement and Food (and you may need many more in future). Your slider functionality can change based on the  implementation of the item object and you do that by adding methods and properties in the protocol.

```
protocol Item {
 var name : String {get set}
 func showDetail()
}

class Advertisement : Item {
   var name : String!
   init(with name: String) {
      self.name = name
   }

    func showDetail() {

    }
}

class Food : Item {
   var name : String!
   init(with name: String) {
      self.name = name
   }

     func showDetail() {

     }
}

class Slider {
   var items: [Item]!  // any object which implements Item protocol
}
```

Let me know if that doesn't solve your problem.