# Vox cocoapod for JSONAPI doesn't build due to fatalError

Tags: ios, swift, cocoapods, fatal-error

So I installed the pod for [Vox on github](https://github.com/aronbalog/Vox) and it's not building at all. Instead, I keep getting the error below.

I through overriding just meant referring to the class in a different place and changing its computer properties? I'm not sure why it's building and would love some help.

```
open class var resourceType: String {
    fatalError("Must override `static var resourceType: String`")        
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to override the class. An [example class](https://github.com/aronbalog/Vox/blob/master/VoxTests/DeserializingSpec.swift) can be found in the Vox repo. 
The class `Player` is a subclass of `Resource`. It overrides the `resourceType` variable. The overridden variable returns the string `"Player"`. Note that it does not return `super.resourceType` since that would call `fatalError`.

```
fileprivate class Player: Resource {
    override class var resourceType: String {
        return "Player"
    }

    @objc dynamic var items: [Resource]?
    @objc dynamic var titles: [String]?
}
```

A more general example of overriding taken from [Overriding properties in swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28786597/overriding-properties-in-swift) is:

```
public class FooButton {
    public var weight: Double = 1.0
}

public class BarButton: FooButton {
    override public var weight: Double = 2.0
}
```

Comment: This is what I was doing but I was putting the overridden class in the wrong place in my swift file.

Comment: Great, glad you got it figured out